# Javascript variable string replacement

Tags: javascript, ajax, chat

Another stupid question.

I believe I understand this right but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
function parseCustomCommands($text, $textParts) {
 if($this->getUserRole() == AJAX_CHAT_ADMIN || $this->getUserRole() == AJAX_CHAT_MODERATOR) {
  switch($textParts[0]) {
   case '/takeover':
   $this->insertChatBotMessage( $this->getChannel(), $text );
   return true;
   default:
   return false;
  }
 }
}
ajaxChat.replaceCustomCommands = function(text, textParts) {
 switch(textParts[0]) {
  case '/takeover':
  text=text.replace('/takeover', ' ');
  return '<span class="chatBotMessage">' + text + '</span>';
  default:
  return text;
 }
}
```

It's executed when /takeover  is this sent and the way I'm looking at it the '/takeover' part is meant to be replaced with nothing leaving just the . This does not seem to be the case..

Is anyone able to point out the mistake in it? I've tried several things with $ in variable names and using different variables to remove it.

$re="/takeover";
$str=text.replace(re, ' ');

I've tried too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a PHP question

[github source](https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat/blob/master/chat/lib/class/AJAXChat.php)

Review the other "insertParsedMessage*" PHP methods

I'm not a PHP developer but it should be something like this based on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$text = str_replace("/takeover","", $text);
```

Comment: it's JS not PHP. It is sorted now. Managed to find the solution.

Seems like it runs away with itself so it needed a ;break in the code.